# fetch() outputs invalid input

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Im trying a simple request to get data from a webserver, but running into an error on the console.

```
fetch('http://tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/test2.json', {mode: 'no-cors'})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(text) {
    console.log('Request successful');

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error)
  });
```

it returns

```
Request failed SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

What gives?

Comment: Are you sure the page contains json? And xan you access that programmatically? Try to log `response` before parsing it

Comment: Im fairly new to fetch(), how would I log responce

Answer (score 1):

If you request the data manually:

```
 curl http://tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/test2.json
```

you see that the output is:

```
{
    "hello": "world"
```

so the json is invalid, and thus `response.json()` fails

Comment: The JSON file is 
{
 "hello": "world"
} , why would it return invalid?

Comment: it was when I first tried the `curl`. Now it has a `%` at the end, as @connexo mentioned

Comment: Interestingly enough, when you use https://onlinecurl.com/ the response seems to not have that %.

Comment: Also when you pipe the curl output into a file `curl http://tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/test2.json > test2.json`, the % is not there.

Comment: Oddly enough, I cant find a hosted working JSON file anywhere to test my code.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file is

```
{
    "hello": "world"
}%
```

Remove that last character `%` from your JSON.

Comment: Im using dreamweaver, maybe its the way its saving the file? https://imgur.com/a/c3wjH

Comment: Open it with an editor like Notepad++ or Sublime and re-check. Are you using Windows?

Comment: Mac Operation System

Comment: Then do `curl http://tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/test2.json` in a terminal window.

Comment: It comes up with that missing bracket, but returns whole with completed brackets on jsonlint.com and status is valid.